# addEventListener for gtag event tracking to Wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, analytics, event-tracking, gtag.js

I want to add Analytics event tracking to a link on a Wordpress page.
The following code is added to the end of the body section. If I inspect the page with developer tools in Chrome, I can see that the EventListener is there for my a tag.
But the event doesn't get sent to Analytics...

```
document.addEventListener("FreeDownloadEventTracking", function(event) { 
    jQuery('div.free-download a').click(function() {
        gtag('event', 'free plugin', {
          'event_category' : 'downloads',
          'event_label' : 'wordpress.org plugin link'
        });
    }); 
});
```

Can anybody tell me what's the problem here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding a jQuery click event inside a `FreeDownloadEventTracking` event, which I presume doesn't exist.

The page would need to trigger `FreeDownloadEventTracking` for your click event to be added to the download link.

I would suggest replacing `FreeDownloadEventTracking` with `DOMContentLoaded` so your `click` event is added to `div.free-download a` when the DOM is loaded. Then clicking the free download link will trigger `gtag`

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed the problem! What a stupid error...